# Is there a list of Gtk2 widgets?

Tags: gtk2

Is there a list of Gtk2 widgets along with screenshots or demonstrations somewhere? I want to find out what a widget is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [widget gallery](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/ch02.html).

Also, there should be a demonstration program installed along with GTK; try running `gtk-demo` at your terminal (`gtk3-demo` for [GTK 3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch03.html).)